# какой то таймаут в работе pcap

Tags: c++, linux, c, libpcap

написал такую простенькую программку, чтобы потом добавить её в программу, которая будет уведомление показывать на экране, если мой компьютер кто-то пингует. почему то приходится ждать определенного времени, прежде чем произойдет вывод пакета, хотя в документации сказано, чтобы этого не было, нужно использовать `pcap_set_timeout`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>

static void read_packets (u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *h, const u_char *bytes) {
    printf("%s: !\n", user);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    struct bpf_program fp;
    char dev[] = "wlp3s0";
    bpf_u_int32 mask;
    bpf_u_int32 net;


    char filter_exp[] = "icmp";

    if (pcap_lookupnet (dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Can't get netmask for device %s\n", dev);
        net = 0;
        mask = 0;
    }

    pcap_t *handle = pcap_create (dev, errbuf);
    pcap_activate (handle);
    
    if (pcap_compile (handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr (handle));
        return (2);
    }

    if (pcap_setfilter (handle, &fp) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr (handle));
        return (2);
    }
    if (pcap_set_timeout (handle, 1000) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't set timeout: %s\n", pcap_geterr (handle));
    }
    
    pcap_loop (handle, 0, read_packets, "cf");
}
```

Comment: винапи возьми, нафиг тебе эта прослойка pcap? и поверь вывести уведомление в винде это сложно.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков я это в linux делаю, и вывести уведомление в linux очень просто.

Comment: Сочувствую... Вижуал же не работает на линуксе...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**man pcap_set_timeout**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_set_timeout) :
>
> pcap_set_timeout   -  set the packet buffer timeout for a not-yet-activated capture handle

Вольный перевод:

> pcap_set_timeout   -  устанавливает таймаут пакетного буфера на ручке захвата, которая ещё не активирована

т.е. `pcap_set_timeout()` нужно вызывать **до** `pcap_activate()`.

---

Ошибку было бы сразу видно, если корректно сравнивавать код возврата с нулём, а не с `-1`:

```
if (pcap_set_timeout (handle, 1000) < 0) {
  /* pcap_geterr() -> can't perform  operation on activated capture */
}
```

Comment: спасибо. я просто вроде и знаю английский, но что-то упускаю, когда читаю.